# What is wrong with path in gulp.spritesmith?

Tags: gulp

I used gulp.spritesmith to make a sprite image. I imported sprite.sass into main.sass and it seems to be working except there is a problem with path to images. I know it is probably some silly mistake but I can't figure out what it is so I would be really greatful if you can help me.
Here is my gulpfile fragment

```
   gulp.task('sprite', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src('assets/img/icons/*.png').pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'sprite.png',
    cssName: 'sprite.sass',
    imgPath: './assets/img/sprite.png' 
  }));
  spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/sass/1-tools')); 
});
```

I'm including image

```
.services-item
    &-design
        @include sprite($heart-services)
```

And these is how it works in the browser.

[image]

Here is my project structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's been nearly 2 years. Hope you have already solved it. AFAIK, among these options of spritesmith, **imgPath ** is the request path relative to the css file rather than the project structure of SASS/images source.

Suppose your css file containing your sprite image reference is in folder **./assets/sass/**, and your image is in **./assets/img/**. In this case you can try change the imgPath option to:

`imgPath: '../img/sprite.png' //use .. back to assets folder, then go down to img folder`